# Bias correction for elastic net

Tags: generalized-linear-model, bias, elastic-net

Background: 
I have a gene expression dataset (p=6000) which I am using it to predict weights of participants (n=31), with elastic net in glmnet package in R.  To estimate the bias of the model, 10-fold cross validation is used: the model is built in training set and the error (residual = actual weight – predicted weight) was calculated in the test set.  The residual – predicted weight figure suggests a strong non-linearity of the data. (*Notice the nonzero slope*)

[image]

Question:
Any suggestion to transform the gene expression dataset so that the weight ~ gene expression can be captured by linear model? 
OR I should use some other non-linear model?